# Image upload with SAS Azure blob can't open

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sas

I already create azure blob SAS and successfully upload image to azure. But the problem is I can't view the blob from azure console, and when I download the file, image can't open.
When I upload txt file, it was success but when I open the file, the text was append with something like this

```
----------------------------913752289048661000170840
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="1_1_1_20190628_080628.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Edit :

Screenshoot from PostMan

Header
[image]

Body
[image]
But it is different when i upload directly from azure console. 
What is the problem?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you used to upload the image file.

Comment: i test it using postman sir, because i'm working for the api to provide the sas url.
Is that possible the problem is when uploading the file?

Comment: It is quite possible. Please share the screenshots of Postman. More than likely you're uploading some text data instead of binary data.

Comment: Pls check edit, i already update with picture..

Comment: Please choose `binary` option and then select `test.jpeg` file.

Comment: thanks sir, it works :))) u help me a lot thank youu!

Answer (score 0):

Choose Binary Option instead of Form-data as body type and click on "Send" button.